# Ensuring JavaScript hasn't been tampered with

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm writing a web application that does some client side encryption of data to ensure that I never get to see what the client is sending to my server. What I am really worried about is if a third party gets access to my JavaScript code and then adds a back door or some other malicious code to my JavaScript file.

Since JavaScript is often hosted on third party CDNs, how does one ensure that a JavaScript file has not been altered or tampered with before the browser downloads it? I'd rather have a big security notice on my page than load some tampered with JavaScript in my clients browser.

In a normal program I would digitally sign the file to ensure that it hasn't been tampered with but I don't think browsers support checking a given signature before they download and / or load a JavaScript file. There must be some solution to this otherwise hosting any files on a CDN would be a huge security risk. SSL only protects the file in transport, not when it is sitting on the CDN server.

Comment: Like if your CDN was hacked?

Comment: @Mathletics Yep. Or a rogue employee at the CDN provider decided to have a little "fun".

Comment: In either case you need to find a new CDN.

Comment: This problem doesn't really have a solution. See this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: @ntoskrnl That's a really interesting article. Thanks. I guess a solution will be harder to implement than originally thought. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: You can also worry about client-side script injection through a compromised client system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the scripts are dynamic, you could store their hashes in database and compare client-side. See http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: What happens if the JavaScript you are using to validate the MD5 hashes has been tampered with? Trust nothing.

Comment: @Cromulent if they tampered with your tamper-proofing, you're outclassed. Serve your files directly. Get your own POPs, pull fiber to them. TRUST NOTHING.

Comment: Serve the validation library directly (as in embedded JS).

Comment: MD5 is considered *completely* broken for this purpose.

Comment: Don't go with single type of hash.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that they reach the client-side unaltered and do not trust any third party CDN, you would need to serve the JavaScript content directly from your source server over HTTPS.

Comparing the hashes (as per [@rishta's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551093/413180) answer) would mean you have to host JavaScript to do this (either in your page or in separate `.js` files served from your server) so you might as well simply serve the client-side encryption code from your server instead which would probably mean less overhead overall.